# Updating RxJava 1.0 code to RxJava 2.0

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm updating some old android app code and can't figure out how to convert code which worked in RxJava/RxAndroid 1.0 to RxJava/RxAndroid 2.0. Code which I'm trying to convert was responsible for getting signal strength indicator and updating a chart with it's value every second. What I managed to hack up in RxJava 2.0 doesn't work at all and after few seconds app crashes with SIGABORT. I can't figure out what I'm missing?

My RxJava 1 code:

```
rx.Observer myObserver = new rx.Observer<Float>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Float aFloat)
            {
                addEntry(aFloat);
            }
        };

        subscription = rx.Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, rx.Observable<Float>>() {
                                @Override
                                public rx.Observable<Float> call(Long aLong) {
                                    return getSignalStrength();
                                }
                            })
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(myObserver);


private rx.Observable<Float> getSignalStrength()
{
    return rx.Observable.create(subscriber ->
    {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Integer value = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        subscriber.onNext(value.floatValue());
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    });
}
```

And what I came up with trying to do RxJava 2.0:

```
        DisposableObserver<Float> disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<Float>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Float value)
            {
                addEntry(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete()
            {
            }
        };

        Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Float>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<Float> apply(Long aLong) throws Exception
                    {
                        return signalStrengthInfo.getSignalStrength();
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(disposableObserver);


private Observable<Float> getSignalStrength()
{
    return Observable.create(subscriber ->
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Integer signalStrength = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
        subscriber.onNext(Float.valueOf(signalStrength));
        subscriber.onComplete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in Rx2 is really embroiled.

Just see simple solution (sorry for kotlin) but if you have some problem with making it with java just ping me in comment.

```
val disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap { getSignalStrength() }
                .doOnNext { addEntry(it) }
                .subscribe()


private fun getSignalStrength(): Observable <Float> {
            val wifiManager = this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
            val signalStrength = wifiManager.connectionInfo.rssi
            return Observable.just(signalStrength.toFloat())
    }
```